# Creating symlink in Laravel (windows)

Tags: laravel, symlink, git-bash

I'm currently having some problems with creating symlink in my Laravel project. I'm currently on `Windows 10 OS` and I'm using `GitBash`.

I need to create symlink from `storage/app/products_content` to `public/products_content`

For that, I'm using the following command:

```
ln -s storage/app/products_content public/products_content
```

The problem is, I'm getting the following error:

> ln: failed to create symbolic link 'public/products_content': No such
>   file or directory

But, when I try to create a symlink like this:

```
ln -s storage/app/products_content products_content
```

It creates it with no errors, but the folder is in my `root` directory, not in `/public`.

What causes this error, could it be permission issues? I'm running GitBash as administrator. Any help appreciated. If I need to provide any additional code, let me know.

Comment: Does `public` even exist?

Comment: It does. My project would't work otherwise. Also, when I create products_content manually in public dir and run this command, it says that folder already exists.

Comment: Well, pls check your paths in your question vs windows, since they differ from what your are asking.

Comment: What do you mean they differ?

Comment: you say: `storage/app/products_content` => `public/products_content`, then: `storage/app/public` => `public/products_content`

Comment: You're right. I edited my question. Still having the same problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try going into the `public` folder, then do:

`ln -s ../storage/app/products_content products_content`

And if that doesn't work, open Command Prompt (not PowerShell)
And "browse" to the `public` folder, then do:

`mklink /D products_content ..\storage\app\products_content`

`mklink` is the same as `ln` except that the target and link is switched.

Comment: then maybe you need to re:install git-scm with a newer version, that has better support for symblinks, you also need to tick in that symblinking should be activated during the installation process.

Comment: this needs to be in the docs for windows users!

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed. It's a couple years later and in case someone sees this, yes, it is still true. Running Windows, serving locally with Laragon. I tried a dozen different things and this was the fix.

Comment: You need to run the command prompt as administrator

Answer (score 6):

Just run: `php artisan storage:link` and modify your path to: `storage/products_content`

Comment: Problem with this is, the project is already in production, there's a lot of images already there. If I do this, my previous images wont work anymore.

Comment: @zlatangoralija gotcha.

Comment: This does not work on Windows and this was Windows specific question.

Answer (score 6):

You may configure additional symbolic links in your filesystems configuration file. Each of the configured links will be created when you run the storage:link command:

```
'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    public_path('images') => storage_path('app/images'),
],
```

Comment: Right from the docs. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when using windows

solution:

In my case, I am using laragon.

LINK CREATION (This is because the php artisan storage: link does not work on windows)

- For this case, you will have access to images
- Open cmd as administrator
- Verify that public access does not work (public \ images)
- Then copy in cmd: mklink / J C: \ laragon \ www \ project-name \ public \ images C: \ laragon \ www \ project-name \ storage \ app \ images

This would be similar to:
**php artisan storage: link**

Take into account that to save in images it must be configured in the filesytem file (conf / filesytem)

```
   'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    public_path('images') => storage_path('app/images'),
],
```

credits : [more info](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)